# Create a loop for regression analysis on dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

```
result = smf.ols('A ~ B', data= datafinal).fit()
```

Here A and B are the columns of the dataframe which contains some time series stock market closing values,

Every time I update the dataframe with new stock prices as columns with different names. I want to run this dynamically.

I want to run this in the loop where the Column names keep changing as the data frame gets updated with new stock values and run regression on the same.

Comment: I tried changing names of the column, but this code doesnt work with changed column names

Comment: by position? `df[df.columns[2]]`

Comment: yes . By position only I tried, but the function is not accepting new column names.

Comment: hey thanks joe, It is working now, if I change it as

datafinal.columns = ['A', 'B']

It accepts new names now.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, if I rename columns as

`datafinal.columns = ['A', 'B']`

It accepts new names now.